# ESLint: Unsafe assignment of an `any` and Unsafe call of an `any` typed value

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Consider the following test code:

```js
import { isHtmlLinkDescriptor } from '@remix-run/react/links'
import invariant from 'tiny-invariant'
import { links } from '~/root'

it('should return a rel=stylesheet', () => {
  const response = links()

  invariant(isHtmlLinkDescriptor(response[0]))

  expect(response[0].rel).toBe('stylesheet')
})
```

and the implementation:

```js
import { LinksFunction } from 'remix'
import tailwindProdUrl from '~/styles/tailwind.css'

export const links: LinksFunction = () => {
  const href =
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? './tailwind.css' : tailwindProdUrl

  return [{ rel: 'stylesheet', href }]
}
```

Where `LinksFunction` is defined [here](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/blob/57949fe0d73f79811b207fb435657da93f5306d6/packages/remix-server-runtime/routeModules.ts#L59-L61) and [here](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/blob/57949fe0d73f79811b207fb435657da93f5306d6/packages/remix-server-runtime/links.ts).

Why is ESLint complaining about "Unsafe assignment of an `any` value." and "Unsafe call of an `any` typed value." in the line below?

```js
const response = links()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong import in the second snippet. It should be:

```
import { LinksFunction } from '@remix-run/server-runtime';
```

or also, if you are working with TypeScript 3.8 or later:

```
import type { LinksFunction } from '@remix-run/server-runtime';
```

The fact that `LinksFunction` is being only used as a type in the code you are showing means that the TypeScript compiler could still succeed in compiling your modules under certain circumstances, despite the missing type definitions.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't fix the issue. The `LinksFunction` can be imported from `remix`, as this package exports everything from the other packages. In any case, I've changed my code to do exact as you suggested, and still have the lint issue.

Comment: On another note, would `import` vs `import type` really give me that lint error? Asking because if that's the case, I find that message really misleading.

Comment: What version of remix are you using? I installed 1.0.6 from MDM and the index.d.ts inside there is referencing files that are not included in the npm package: "./client", "./server" and "./platform".

Comment: Well, it's not `import` vs `import type` that makes a difference, but the fact that `LinksFunction` is only a type, not the name of a class or another JavaScript identifier.

Comment: I understand that, and I just added a rule to my tsconfig to ensure I onlu iport types using `import type`, but it's not like it doesn't work. I'm using `remix` 1.0.6 as well. btw, my VSCode shows me TS infers the type of `response` correctly. Autocompletion of methods under response also works fine, but ESLint gives me that error.